# How did Harris throw Mahoney out?

Tags: plot-explanation, police-academy

In Police Academy Commandant Lassard tells Mahoney that he cannot throw him out.

However, later, Lt Harris does exactly that when Mahoney takes the blame for the canteen fight.

I am guessing that the script was just not thought through in that detail but, on the off chance(!), is this ever actually explained?

Comment: Any questions or unclarities about the existing answers?

Comment: No, I was leaving it open in case anyone else had any input but it has probably been left long enough

Comment: Well, you don't have to accept it just because of my comment (thank you, though). I just wanted to make sure the question wasn't forgotten.

Comment: TBH I had forgotten it :-) However, I think the answer you gave is the only one which really makes sense!

Comment: Did anybody notice that mahoney shows up at the end of the movie after being thrown out with no explanation?

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer to the question. Good catch though. You may want to post this as a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wasn't so much that *Lassard* was technically unable to throw him out, he just had promised that to *Captain Reed*, who chose the Police Academy as an alternative to jail for teaching *Mahoney* some discipline. So it was more a personal than a technical decision to not throw him out for the many pranks he tried, since those were probably not strict (even if possible) reasons for getting expelled.

But once *Mahoney* started (or claimed to have started) a fight with another recruit, he had crossed a line where even *Lassard* as commandant wasn't able to keep him at the Academy anymore and *Harris* finally got a legitimate reason to expel *Mahoney*. Fighting was just too heavy a misdeed to be ignored on the commandant's preference and was probably strictly written as a reason for expellance, which is also stated by *Copeland* (or *Mahoney* himself?) just before the fight, I think (and was in fact also the reason why *Hightower* was thrown out).

At least that's how I understood the story, or how one could make some sense out of this. (Still one could ask the question why *Mahoney* didn't try this earlier, when he still *wanted* to get thrown out, but I'd really attribute this to some logic sacrificed for the sake of the story, as like you said, *"the script was just not thought through in that detail"*.)

Comment: Are you trying to say that Mahoney couldn't be kicked out for *performance* related issues, but that he can be for *misconduct?*

Comment: I always considered there to be some leeway when rating performance, but not in cases of misconduct. It's similar in most educational systems (at least here in Germany): There are basic rules determining when you're considered a "lost case" and essentially kicked out. However in most cases there are exceptions that can be made by those examining/asserting your case.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Well, I guess (given I understood you correctly). Since *"performance related issues"* lay a bit more in the eye and judgement of the Commandant (who didn't *want* to expel *Mahoney*), while *"misconduct"* was a stricter reason for expellance, one that *Lassard* couldn't just disregard that easily.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Or to put it another way, he **could** be kicked out for *"performance related issues"*, but he **had to** be kicked out for *"misconduct"*.